# Linux How to install udev?

Tags: linux

I downloaded udev-172, but I don't know how to install it.

Here are the files I downloaded:

```
 -003:~/Downloads/udev-172$ ls
aclocal.m4  config.h.in   extras        libudev      NEWS    TODO
autogen.sh  configure     gtk-doc.make  m4           README  udev
build-aux   configure.ac  init          Makefile.am  rules   udev.conf
ChangeLog   COPYING       INSTALL       Makefile.in  test
```

Comment: Off Topic. However, steps generally include: `less README`, `less INSTALL`, `./configure`, `make`, etc ..

Comment: Use your packet manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok sry for that stupid newbie Question.

```
./configure
make
make install
```